# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: `receipt` is mandatory razorpay

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, payment, razorpay

I'm following [this](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/#create-an-order/) documentation to create an order and they have clearly stated that the receipt is an optional parameter then why I'm getting

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: `receipt` is mandatory razorpay
```

here is the error[image]

this is the code

```
const createOrder = async (req, res) => {
  const amount = parseInt(req.body.amount) * 100;
  const currency = req.body.currency;
  var options = {
    amount,
    currency,
  };

  const instance = await razorpay.orders.create(options);
  if (instance) {
    const order_id = instance.id;
    const transaction = new Transactions({ order_id, user_id,details:instance });
    transaction.save();
    res.status(200).json(instance);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the `razorpay` library that was [fixed over a year ago](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-node/commit/80044a4d1f54cdee6e8f5b81ddbcccba5812c175).

Make sure you are using the latest version of the package. If the fix wasn't published, you could try using this commit directly:

```
npm i razorpay/razorpay-node#80044a4d1f54cdee6e8f5b81ddbcccba5812c175
```

If this doesn't work either, you could open an issue with the library on GitHub.